# Python: For loop Vs. Map

Tags: python, optimization

I am currently in the process of optimising the translation part of my software, which translates co-ordinates `x` amount of times. My current translation code is in the `translate` function and the supposedly optimised portion in the `translate_map` function.

I read [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) that the `map` function should be used instead of `for` loops where possible because the loop is performed in C.

When I run a test case below, the `map` function actually runs slower than a standard `for` loop. Why does the `map` perform slower than the conventional `for` loop? How could I optimise the translate function to run faster?

```
import time

def translate(atom_list):
    for i in atom_list:
        i[1]+=1
        i[2]+=1
        i[3]+=1

atoms = [[1,1,1,1]]*1000
start = time.time()
for x in xrange(10000):
    translate(atoms)
print time.time() - start


atoms = [[1,1,1,1]]*1000
start = time.time()
def translate_map(atom_list):
    atom_list[1]+=1
    atom_list[2]+=1
    atom_list[3]+=1
for x in xrange(10000):
    map(translate_map,atoms)
print time.time() - start
```

output:

```
2.92705798149
4.14674210548
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use numpy for this?

Comment: use `timeit` module for timing your code.

Comment: Use NumPy instead of doing such micro-optimizations. It may give several orders of magnitude speedup if used correctly, while `map` may save perhaps 10% running time.

Comment: Note that your timings are not "fair". `translate` is different from `translate_map`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments no reason not to use numpy, i'll change my code to use numpy.

Comment: @jamylak Seeing that numpy will speed my code up more than using map, will you post this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @Harpal It's a good answer but I can't be bothered to put it up, somebody else probably will though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect most of the overhead you're seeing with your `map` implementation comes from function call overhead. The `translate` function does all its work within a single loop, so there's just a single function call for the whole process. The implementation with `map` makes a separate function call for every item in the list.

A second source of overhead (though I suspect it is small compared to the function calls) is that `map` creates a list with the return values from the function. Since `translate_map` doesn't have a `return` statement, this will be all `None` values. Note that in Python 3, `map` is a generator, so your `map` version won't work at all unless you iterate over the results from the `map` call. The explicit loop is much clearer though, so I'd stick with that (if you don't go for numpy).

Oh, yes, `numpy` would make this much easier (and almost certainly faster too):

```
def translate(arr): # arr should be a numpy array
    arr += 1
```

That's it! No loops needed (at the Python level).